# Magento 2 multistore product setup

Tags: magento2, catalog, stores

I am using magento 2 , and i created many store and store view. i am getting trouble in setup like:

```
1. how to assign one product to multiple store and store view at the time of create product.
2. how to set different price per store view.
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - **how to assign one product to multiple store and store view at the time of create product.**

You can add comma separated values for under "website" , "store" columns to assign single products to multiple sites / stores

**Hint** : ( add single product manually and assign that product to multiple stores, storeviews and other changes which you want to make and then export this csv. then you will get an idea how to add / update other products via csv ).

**2. how to set different price per store view.**
As of Magento 2.2.6 versions you can not set different price for different store view basis, by default price is set **Global** it can't be changed on store view levels.

However you can change price per **Website** Level. You can check configuration under :

> Stores > Configurations > Catalog > Price ( Tab )

Comment: is it not possible to change the default price setting, from website to store view?

Comment: No it is not , you would need some extension or need customization.

Comment: can you please guide some customization process